# Thin or Puma: What to use for a Rails Chat server using Faye?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, thin, faye, puma

As a learning experience, I'm trying to build a Chat Application for both Android and iOS that allows group chats (like Whatsapp) with a chat server in Rails. After a bit of research, I decided to go with **Faye** since it seemed easy enough to implement. I'm following these tutorials to do that:

- [Messaging with Faye - Railscasts #260](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye)
- [How to Use Faye as a Real-Time Push Server in Rails](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-faye-as-a-real-time-push-server-in-rails--net-22600)

For my Production stack, I was thinking of setting up `Nginx` with `Thin` or `Puma` but I can't understand which would be better and what would be the 'proper' way to set up a chat server in production.

---

I know this question might be a little subjective, but googling/researching this for the past week has got me even more conflicted since most of the examples are using `Thin` but most articles prefer `Puma`.

I would also appreciate if you could give references and examples with your answers. Thank you.

Comment: Why is this question marked for Closing?

Comment: @Natrium this question is a poor fit over there for the same reasons as here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/ruby-app-server-arena-pt1

Here is comparing of various servers with explanation of pros and cons of each.

Comment: I feel like that article doesn't truly understand how Thin works. It only has one thread due to being evented, and then they complain that in the `sleep` test, it performed horribly without explaining that the sleep will completely stop a single threaded server.